# CodeIgniter Routing Folder Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have the CodeIgniter controller file, placed in here

```
controllers/public/Pubweb.php
```

and I want to set that file as my default controller, but when I change the default controller route value, it will goes error. My route code :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'public/pubweb';
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: can you post the exact error you got? Runtime, syntax etc?

Comment: The error said 404 Page Not Found, The page you requested was not found. But i had the Pubweb.php already in my folder

Comment: Are you navigating to the correct url? Assuming you are not modifying the url (to remove the index.php) you would want to: `http:[YOUR URL]/index.php/public/pubweb/`

Comment: What's your controller class name ? may be it's different whit your controller file name.

Comment: @James Umm i used .htaccess to remove the index.php but i think it doesn't wrong with my .htaccess file because i can access all file controller except my default controller

Comment: @EkoJunaidiSalam my class name is Pubweb with `public function index()` as my routing URL

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397000/default-controller-inside-subfolder-codeigniter-3-not-working). Just as side notice, make your own `MY_Router.php` in `APPPATH . 'core'` directory with code changes instead changing system core file.

Comment: @LSNRabbani How did you go I added my answer

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Sorry i not try it yet. I'm still fixing another problem. But when i try it and success i'll comment immediatly

Comment: @wolfgang1983 thanks man ! It works :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> On **CodeIgniter 3** It does not allow you to have a sub folder on `$route['default_controller']` you will instead need to create a MY_Router.php file like below.

You will need to create a MY_Router.php in

```
application > core > MY_Router.php
```

Here is a MY_Router.php file that should allow you to use `$route['default_controller'] = 'public/pubweb';` in Codeigniter 3

```
<?php

class MY_Router extends CI_Router {
    protected function _set_default_controller() {

        if (empty($this->default_controller)) {

            show_error('Unable to determine what should be displayed. A default route has not been specified in the routing file.');
        }
        // Is the method being specified?
        if (sscanf($this->default_controller, '%[^/]/%s', $class, $method) !== 2) {
            $method = 'index';
        }

        // This is what I added, checks if the class is a directory
        if( is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$class) ) {

            // Set the class as the directory

            $this->set_directory($class);

            // $method is the class

            $class = $method;

            // Re check for slash if method has been set

            if (sscanf($method, '%[^/]/%s', $class, $method) !== 2) {
                $method = 'index';
            }
        }

        if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->directory.ucfirst($class).'.php')) {

            // This will trigger 404 later

            return;
        }
        $this->set_class($class);
        $this->set_method($method);
        // Assign routed segments, index starting from 1
        $this->uri->rsegments = array(
            1 => $class,
            2 => $method
        );
        log_message('debug', 'No URI present. Default controller set.');
    }
}
```

Make sure your files have first letter upper case on file name and class name. `Pubweb.php` and `class Pubweb extends CI_Controller {}`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new file in the main controllers folder for routing purpose. for example, I have a directory structure like `'controllers/coming/Commingsoon.php'`.
if I want to run `Commingsoon` as my default controller so i will do this:

create new file in controllers folder: `Main_controller.php`:

```
class Main_controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent:: __construct();
    }

    public function index(){    
        redirect('comming'); 
    }
}
```

and in routes.php file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'main_controller';

$route['comming'] = 'comming/commingsoon/index';
```

hope this will help...