# Codeigniter - Routing to subfolders not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello im having an issue here im new in learning codeigniter but my main problem is i cannot locate the url i want to have like for this:

I need to type `http://localhost/ciHrs/admin/pages` whereas i only want to get the url `http://localhost/ciHrs/admin/` please kindly explain how can I access this url. and lastly the `Default Controller` I want to access `http://localhost/ciHrs/admin/` directly. thanks

I have a subfolder name **admin** on controller and subfolder name **admin** on view and subfolder **admin** on model

here is my routes

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['admin/rooms'] = "admin/rooms/index";
$route['default_controller'] = 'admin/pages/view/dashboard';
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/pages/view/$1";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

my Controller to access this page

```
<?php 

class Pages extends CI_Controller{
    public function view(){
        $data['title'] = 'Dashboard';

        $this->load->view('admin/templates/header');
        $this->load->view('admin/pages/dashboard',$data);
        $this->load->view('admin/templates/footer');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following rules on your routes :

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['default_controller'] = 'admin/pages/view/dashboard';
$route['admin'] = "admin/pages";
$route['admin/'] = "admin/pages";
$route['admin/rooms'] = "admin/rooms/index";
$route['admin/(:any)'] = "admin/pages/view/$1";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: hello kindly explain why there is 2 admin/pages ?

Comment: Sure @happycoding, the first rule is for the admin url **without** trailing slash, and the second is for the admin url **with** trailing slash, I provide the second rule since you're likely going to access using the trailing slash url

Comment: can you please answer my another question sir please here is the link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55048666/how-the-integration-works-between-the-front-end-and-back-end)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not relying to [CI uri routing](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

**EXPLAINING**

On your routes:

```
$route['admin/rooms'] = "admin/rooms/index";
```

So here, you can call the domain and the corresponding `admin/rooms` depends on your `$route` definition. It looks like this: `http://example.com/admin/rooms` instead of `http://example.com/admin/rooms/index`

The `default_controller` seems to be loaded when the cookie session was set. You can only call the domain itself and it will load automatically the `default_controller` that you set.

Hence, on your question you said that you only want to get `http://localhost/ciHrs/admin/`, why not define in on `$route` just like this:

```
$route['ciHrs/admin/'] = "ciHrs/admin/pages";
```

or considering if the `pages` uri is dynamic set your route to:

```
$route['ciHrs/admin/(:any)'] = "ciHrs/admin/$1";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: sir i tried this `$route['ciHrs/admin/'] = "ciHrs/admin/pages";` and this `$route['ciHrs/admin/(:any)'] = "ciHrs/admin/$1";` but it didnt work i typed in browser like this `http://localhost/ciHrs/admin/` still showing 404 error :(

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713411/codeigniter-routing-folder-error)

Comment: hello i can skip default controller what i want is to remove `pages` so i can just directly go to this uri `http://localhost/ciHrs/admin/`

Comment: Can you explain what is `ciHrs`? Is that a class or function?

Comment: `ciHrs` is my main folder. it is the codeigniter folder :)