# Codeigniter 3.0 - Unable to load the requested file:subfolder/file.php

Tags: routes, codeigniter-3

I use Codeigniter 3.0. I found that not able to route to file in subfolder.
After, i edit file route.php in system/core like this guide :
[default controller inside subfolder codeigniter 3 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397000/default-controller-inside-subfolder-codeigniter-3-not-working)
Page could routing right. 
But, i get error after upload host like that :
***"Unable to load the requested file: frontend/Home.php"***
my structure :

```
-controllers
  -frontend
     Home.php
-views
  - frontend
     Home.php
```

My route file :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'frontend/Home';
```

I checked name of class, up-case the first character.

Comment: "Unable to load the requested file" would seem to be it's the the *view* not loading; if it was the controller - it would be a 404 error message. Double check if you have the syntax right for the view load `$this->load->view( "frontend/home" );`

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter looks for `Frontend` controller with `home` method. You can solve it on two ways. First iw to make `Home.php` controller in `controllers` directory with next code:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('Restricted area!');

class Frontend extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->home();
    }

    public function home()
    {
        redirect('frontend/home', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

with `APPPATH.'config/routes.php'` code

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

Second way is to use custom made router class:

```
<?php

/*
 * Custom router function v 0.1
 *
 * Add functionality : read into more than one sub-folder
 *
 */

class MY_Router extends CI_Router
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function _validate_request($segments)
    {
        if (file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$segments[0].EXT))
        {
            return $segments;
        }

        if (is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$segments[0]))
        {
            $this->set_directory($segments[0]);
            $segments = array_slice($segments, 1);

            /* ----------- ADDED CODE ------------ */

            while(count($segments) > 0 && is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->directory.$segments[0]))
            {
                // Set the directory and remove it from the segment array
                $this->set_directory($this->directory . $segments[0]);
            $segments = array_slice($segments, 1);
            }

            /* ----------- END ------------ */

            if (count($segments) > 0)
            {
                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->fetch_directory().$segments[0].EXT))
                {
                    show_404($this->fetch_directory().$segments[0]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $this->set_class($this->default_controller);
                $this->set_method('index');

                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->fetch_directory().$this->default_controller.EXT))
                {
                    $this->directory = '';
                    return array();
                }

            }

            return $segments;
        }

        show_404($segments[0]);
    }
}
```

[Credits](https://glennpratama.wordpress.com/2009/10/20/multi-level-subfolder-for-controller-in-codeigniter/).

Comment: thanks for your reply ! but my problem is not able route on host. i checked but still not working.

Comment: Something wrong here.
$route['default_controller'] = 'home'; 
=> CI will find home.php class in controllers folder (not have :D) because home.php in frontend sub folder
Btw, any solution does not redirecting ?