# CodeIgniter : page not found issue appear when i call default controller in Php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Structure of my controller directory:

```
--Controller
  --frontend
    --user_controller
```

When i call default controller it says `404 page not found`

Route i have set :

```
$route['default_controller'] = "frontend/user_controller";
$route['admin_panel/site'] = "site";
$route['admin_panel'] = "backend/admin_controller/dashboard";
$route['admin_panel/login'] = "backend/admin_controller/index";
$route['admin_panel/(:any)'] = "backend/admin_controller/$1";

$route['admin_panel/(:any)/(.*)'] = "backend/admin_controller/$1/$2";
```

And when i run `http://localhost/example/frontend/user_controller` then it works.

So but didn't work this url : `http://localhost/example`

Comment: can you please provide more information as to the structure of your controller... Not enough to go on... The error is occurring as you are not calling the right place. is there a 'public function index()' in your user_controller?

Comment: don't place the controller inside in folder if want to do you need some extra change.

Comment: review this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955335/routing-controllers-in-sub-folders-codeigniter/13955395#13955395

Answer (score 0):

Please try with: move default controller at bottom

```
$route['admin_panel/site'] = "site";
$route['admin_panel'] = "backend/admin_controller/dashboard";
$route['admin_panel/login'] = "backend/admin_controller/index";
$route['admin_panel/(:any)'] = "backend/admin_controller/$1";

$route['admin_panel/(:any)/(.*)'] = "backend/admin_controller/$1/$2";
$route['default_controller'] = "frontend/user_controller";
```

Comment: It wouldnt, default can be at top no problems

Answer (score 0):

`Codeigniter` will not allow `default controller` to be in a sub directory.
You have to rewrite it as

```
$route['default_controller'] = "user_controller";
```

And place that directly in the `controller` folder

You can refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30397000/default-controller-inside-subfolder-codeigniter-3-not-working) to avoid this. But I didn't tested it.

**It is better to avoid the core functionalities as it may affect the updates.**

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this but potentially you could use this to get around the sub-folder?

```
$route['frontend'] = 'frontend/user_controller';
$route['default_controller'] = 'frontend';
```

need to make sure there is a 'public function index()' in there though as you aren't specifying the method to load...